# My query is slow when ever I select inside concat or group_concat and I want to return them in form of JSON. how can I make it faster?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a discount table (productdiscounts) where I inserted product ID and the accounts that I wish to give discount. e.g all users under ABC account should be given a discount of 10% and users under account XZS should be given a discount of 90%, etc.

secondly I selected all the available accounts and the discounts  associated to them as alldiscounts for staff to see which accounts have discount on a product.

```
 SELECT 
      products.manufacturer as manufacturerID, stock.expiryDate,
      *coalesce((select discount from productdiscounts where(productID=products.id and branchID=? and isActive='1' and patients.billingAccounts like concat('%\"',productdiscounts.accountID,'\"%')) order by discount desc limit 1),0.00) as discount*,
     **concat('[',(select 
    group_concat('{\"productID\":\"',productdiscounts.productID,'\",\"accountID\":\"',productdiscounts.accountID,'\",\"discount\":\"',productdiscounts.discount,'\",\"accountName\":\"',accounts.name,'\",\"accountNo\":\"',accounts.accountNo,'\"}') from productdiscounts 
    left join accounts on(productdiscounts.accountID=accounts.id)
    where(productdiscounts.productID=products.id and productdiscounts.branchID = ? and productdiscounts.isActive = '1' )),']') as allDiscounts**
    from products
```

This is a sample patient record
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qeII.png)

This is how i store each product with accounts that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLdB6.png)

A patient can have more than one account which 99% of them do, and that's why I couldn't use "accounID = ". E.g A patient maybe associated with his corporate account which doesn't cover all the services and has to use his private account to pay for those services not covered under his/her corporate account.

I associated corporate accounts and their discount on each product so that I can check the patient's billing accounts while searching a product and if the product is covered under any or all the patient's billing account, then return the discount, otherwise return 0.00.

Because it's the same query for searching a product and listing all the products. In this section, I'm returning all the discounts associated to a product in order to guide staff on the status of the product.

```
concat('[',(select group_concat('{\"productID\":\"',productdiscounts.productID,'\",\"accountID\":\"',productdiscounts.accountID,'\",\"discount\":\"',productdiscounts.discount,'\",\"accountName\":\"',accounts.name,'\",\"accountNo\":\"',accounts.accountNo,'\"}') from productdiscounts 
                                    left join accounts on(productdiscounts.accountID=accounts.id)
                                    where(productdiscounts.productID=products.id and productdiscounts.branchID = ? and productdiscounts.isActive = '1' )),']') as allDiscounts
```

FULL CODE FOR REVIEW

```
$searchSQL="select 
                                distinct products.id,
                                products.type as productType,
                                products.brand,
                                products.status,
                                products.productCode,
                                products.generics,
                                stock.stockID,
                                stock.stockIn,
                                stock.description,
                                stock.quantity as stockQty,
                                pricetags.costPrice,
                                pricetags.sellingPrice,
                                pricetags.percentageMarkup,
                                countries.country as manufacturer,
                                products.manufacturer as manufacturerID,
                                stock.expiryDate,
                                coalesce((select discount from productdiscounts where(productID=products.id and branchID=? and isActive='1' and patients.billingAccounts like concat('%\"',productdiscounts.accountID,'\"%')) order by discount desc limit 1),0.00) as discount,
                                concat('[',(select group_concat('{\"productID\":\"',productdiscounts.productID,'\",\"accountID\":\"',productdiscounts.accountID,'\",\"discount\":\"',productdiscounts.discount,'\",\"accountName\":\"',accounts.name,'\",\"accountNo\":\"',accounts.accountNo,'\"}') from productdiscounts 
                                left join accounts on(productdiscounts.accountID=accounts.id)
                                where(productdiscounts.productID=products.id and productdiscounts.branchID = ? and productdiscounts.isActive = '1' )),']') as allDiscounts
                            from products 
                            left join stock on (products.id=stock.productID) 
                            left join pricetags on (stock.priceTag=pricetags.id) 
                            left join countries on (products.manufacturer=countries.id)
                            left join diagnosis on (diagnosis.diagnosisRef=?)
                            left join patients on (patients.patientNo=diagnosis.patientNo)
                            where(
                                (
                                    products.productCode=? or 
                                    products.generics like concat('%\"',?,'%\"%') or  
                                    (";
                                    foreach($needleArray as $needle){
                                        $searchSQL.="(products.brand like concat(?,'%') or products.brand like concat('% ',?,'%')) and ";
                                        $productsQParams[]=$needle;
                                        $productsQParams[]=$needle;
                                    }
                                    $searchSQL=rtrim($searchSQL," and ");
                                    $searchSQL.="
                                    )
                                ) and (";
                                if($chkStockQty === "True"){
                                    $searchSQL.=" `stock`.`quantity` > 0 and ";
                                }
                                $searchSQL.=" stock.branchID={$branchID} and 
                                    stock.isActive='1' and 
                                    products.status='active'
                                )
                            ) order by products.brand limit $offset,$rowCount";
```

SEE FINAL OUTPUT HERE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l35V.png)

This is the query. I hope is what you are asking for. Thank You

```
select 
                                distinct products.id,
                                products.type as productType,
                                products.brand,
                                products.status,
                                products.productCode,
                                products.generics,
                                stock.stockID,
                                stock.stockIn,
                                stock.description,
                                stock.quantity as stockQty,
                                pricetags.costPrice,
                                pricetags.sellingPrice,
                                pricetags.percentageMarkup,
                                countries.country as manufacturer,
                                products.manufacturer as manufacturerID,
                                stock.expiryDate,
                                coalesce((select discount from productdiscounts where(productID=products.id and branchID=1 and isActive='1' and patients.billingAccounts like concat('%\"',productdiscounts.accountID,'\"%')) order by discount desc limit 1),0.00) as discount,
                                concat('[',(select group_concat('{\"productID\":\"',productdiscounts.productID,'\",\"accountID\":\"',productdiscounts.accountID,'\",\"discount\":\"',productdiscounts.discount,'\",\"accountName\":\"',accounts.name,'\",\"accountNo\":\"',accounts.accountNo,'\"}') from productdiscounts 
                                left join accounts on(productdiscounts.accountID=accounts.id)
                                where(productdiscounts.productID=products.id and productdiscounts.branchID = 1 and productdiscounts.isActive = '1' )),']') as allDiscounts
                            from products 
                            left join stock on (products.id=stock.productID) 
                            left join pricetags on (stock.priceTag=pricetags.id) 
                            left join countries on (products.manufacturer=countries.id)
                            left join diagnosis on (diagnosis.diagnosisRef='')
                            left join patients on (patients.patientNo=diagnosis.patientNo)
                            where(
                                (
                                    products.generics like concat('%pan%') 
                                ) and ( stock.branchID=1 and 
                                    stock.isActive='1' and 
                                    products.status='active'
                                )
                            )
```

Comment: I'm having too much trouble parsing the query.  Please provide the generated query (without '**', `\`, etc) and shorten the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

```
and  patients.billingAccounts like concat('%\"',productdiscounts.accountID,
                                        '\"%')
```

Is that fishing around in a JSON string?  Can't you supply the whole accountID so you don't have to do the slow `LIKE` with a leading wild card?

With `=` instead of `LIKE`, this might help the first subquery:

```
INDEX(branchID, isActive, productID, AccountID, discount)
```

It might be more practical to do

```
 SELECT COALESCE(MAX(discount), 0) ...
```

instead of the `ORDER BY discount DESC LIMIT 1`.

The other parts may benefit from

```
patients:  INDEX(billingAccounts)
productdiscounts:  INDEX(accountID)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`